# Cannot convert type 'Observable<Object> to type 'Observable<any[]>

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple method that calls an api and returns a list of companies. The applications works and I can view my companies without a problem, however, TypeScript seems to be unhappy with my syntax and I am not sure why.

Here is my error message:
[image]

**company.service.ts**

```
getCompanies() {
    return this._http.get(URL_COMPANY)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**companies.component.ts**

```
companies: Observable<any[]>;
constructor(private _companyService: CompanyService, private router: Router) { }


ngOnInit() {
    this.companies = this._companyService.getCompanies();
}
```

**companies.component.html**

```
    <tr *ngFor="let c of companies | async">
        <td><a (click)="gotoCompany(c)">{{ c.name }}</a></td>
    </tr>
```

I've been following the examples from John Papa and Ward Bell's Play by Play video and the syntax is the same as theirs, however, they are in Visual Studio Code and I am in Visual Studio 2015. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not sure where `Object` came from in the first place, usually `any` should be preferred. It isn't obvious that `json()` returns an array. If it does, I guess the proper type should be specified, `.map((response: Response): any[] => response.json())`.

Comment: Tried as you suggested, the syntax warning still persist.  I even tried this, `.map((response: Response): Observable<any[]> => response.json())` and it still didn't go away. Code still runs though. Very weird.

Comment: I've only seen this as a resharper warning.

Comment: I had the same issue and i think pblack is right, with VS 2015 & Resharper this error shows up, but ultimately does nothing. I did used Resharper to make it go away but it just wrapped everything in a weird call:

 return (this._http.get(this._url)
            .map(response => response.json() as IModel[])
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError)) as any;

Notice the ) as any; at the end... very weird behavior from Resharper.

Comment: Weird... resharper just had me change my List Component as well:

 .subscribe((models: any) => this.models= models,

Comment: Thanks, I believe it was just resharper doing it! I opened the solution without resharper and it has gone away.